# Switch Statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
switch (parseInt(charCode))
    {
        case (charCode >= 65 && charCode <=90): //UPPERCASE
            alert("UP");
        break;

        case (charCode >= 97 && charCode <=122): //LOWERCASE
            alert("LO");
        break;

        case (charCode >= 48 && charCode <=57): //NNUMBERS
            alert("NUM");
        break


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrong syntax alltogether

Comment: What does it currently do? What do you want to achieve? What's in `parseInt(charCode)`?

Comment: Despite the fact you're mixing if and switch statements :)

Comment: Switch can only be used to check against specific values, not ranges. Read this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**edit**] Let's add this disclaimer: this use of `switch` is considered EVIL or ABUSIVE. Some Disciples Of The Javascript also consider the use of *ternaries* as a major SIN. So beware of using them, because [hell](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/eoq10/the_javascript_cockroach_from_hell/) may await you, so the Gospel goes.

You can use `switch` like this <sup>**1**</sup>:

```
switch (true) {
   case (parseInt(charCode) >= 65 && parseInt(charCode) <=90): //UPPERCASE
       alert("UP");
       break;
   case (parseInt(charCode) >= 97 && parseInt(charCode) <=122): //LOWERCASE
       alert("LO");
       break;
   case (parseInt(charCode) >= 48 && parseInt(charCode) <=57): //NNUMBERS
       alert("NUM");
       break;
   default: break
}
```

it's pretty bulky. You don't have to use `parseInt` if you derive `charCode` came from `event.keyCode`. If you need to use `parseInt`, don't forget to provide the [radix](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/parseint.html), or better still, use `Number` to convert to a number.

Anyway using a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary) is an alternative for this:

```
alert( charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 
        ? 'UP'
        : charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122
        ? 'LO'
        : charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57 
        ? 'NUM'
        : 'OTHER'
);
```

[***edit***] Let's see if the following alternative can satisfy the church of Javascript Coders...

Another alternative is using a `RegExp` with the character derived from the `keyCode`:

```
var chr      = String.fromCharCode(charCode),
    alertval =    /[a-z]/.test(chr) ?  'LO'
                : /[A-Z]/.test(chr) ?  'UP'
                : /[0-9]/.test(chr) ?  'NUM'
                : 'OTHER';
    alert(alertval);
```

As a last alternative (man, javascript is *so* versatile!) I present:

```
var check = String.fromCharCode(charCode)
             .replace(/([a-z])|([A-Z])|([0-9])|(.+)/,
                function(a,b,c,d) {
                  return b ? 'LO' : c ? 'UP' : d ? 'NUM' : 'OTH';
             });
```

<sup>**1**</sup> [some notes](http://getmockery.com/blog/archives/80) on that 'trick'

Comment: What ... a ... *horrible* ...idea. :-) Still, though, it should *work*, cases *are* evaluated in order.

Comment: Thanks, I remembered that's how to do it. It is the exact correct method and far better than a string of ugly if else statements.

Comment: @thebounder: Ugliness, like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder. :-)

Comment: I remember now that I forgot that and I am so happy I did forget it.

Comment: @all: that's why I provided an alternative ;~)

Comment: Oh yeah, let's see if we can abuse other language constructs to make it as obscure as possible ;)))

Comment: Horrible idea, also supposing this could work as expected, it should make use of side effects of operators, making (at least) the source unreadable... :(

Comment: @D.S. let's say unreadability [also] is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Koolinc, TRUST is in the eye of the beholder, the BEAUTY too. But not unreadability. Why making a simple thing so complex?

Comment: Phew, amazing how easy it is to 'irritate people and make things generally annoying' (after Monty Python). Is it the weather? Should I change my (gr)avatar? Have I fallen out of grace? Am I using the wrong javascript scriptures (the ones where `ternaries` are ok)? Who knows? I just wanted to provide the OP with an answer and some alternatives.

Comment: My personal irritation came from your String.formCharCode example which is in my opinion a rehash of my simple `if (regexp.test())` suggestion with your horrific ternary.

Comment: Sorry about that @mplungjan, but I think we were editing around the same time on the regexp.test answer. I didn't read your edit before I added my `.test` solution, that much I know. Anyway, I suppose the OP has choice enough now. AFAIAC ... next question please.

Answer (score 5):

Cases must be single values, not expressions. If you need to use expressions, use an `if` `else if` series:

```
var numCharCode = parseInt(charCode, 10); // Always best to include the radix argument
if (numCharCode >= 65 && numCharCode <=90) {       //UPPERCASE
    alert("UP");
}
else if (numCharCode >= 97 && numCharCode <=122) { //LOWERCASE
    alert("LO");
}
else if (numCharCode >= 48 && numCharCode <=57) {  //NNUMBERS
    alert("NUM");
}
```

(Always assuming `charCode` really is a string in the first place. The name suggests it's already a number.)

---

**Off-topic**: Your logic is English-centric (and fails even for English, on words we've copied from other languages, like "naïve"). If that's okay, great, but if not you'll want to look more into how you reliably determine the case of a character in a language-neutral way. [More in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816905/checking-if-a-string-starts-with-a-lowercase-letter/3816968#3816968) here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have remembered how to do it myself:

charCode = parseInt(charCode);
  switch (true)
  {
   case (charCode >= 65 && charCode <=90): //UPPERCASE
   // return true;
    alert("UP");
   break;

   case (charCode >= 97 && charCode <=122): //UPPERCASE
   // return true;
    alert("LO");
   break;

   case (charCode >= 48 && charCode <=57): //NUMBERS
   // return true;
    alert("NUM");
   break;

   case (charCode == 8 || charCode == 13):
    return true;
   break;

   default:
    return false;
   break;

  
  }

Comment: Actually it even fails for some "original" English words (definition tricky due to how the language came to be). "encyclopædia" comes to mind.

Comment: @Tomalek: "encyclopædia" is copied from Greek, indirectly via Latin, which is why it has the ash diphthong ("æ") which is fairly common in transliterations of words from the Greek to Latin alphabets. (English is *such* a mutt. :-) ) But again, exactly, this is an English word and has been for nearly 500 years, and for most of that time it was spelt with the diphthong.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't take as true the supposition about Javascript uses ASCII character table (doesn't it use UTF8?), so instead of numerical value comparison, just use character (string) value comparison.
You shouldn't use switch statement in such a way: as in your example, it performs a (value and type, "===") comparison between parseInt(charCode) (which should be an integer) and boolean expression values such that returned by your case statements.
Use and IF chain, as follows (supposing charCode is still a string value):

```
if (charCode >= 'A' && charCode <='Z') { //UPPERCASE
            alert("UP");
} else if (charCode >= 'a' && charCode <='z') { //LOWERCASE
            alert("LO");
        break;
} else if (charCode >= '0' && charCode <='9'): //NNUMBERS
            alert("NUM");
}
```

For ASCII numerical value of a char, use Javascript "asc" function, and so if you charcode is coming from a key event, you can use the inverse, the chr(keyCode) function in order to obtain a string (character) value of your already numerical keycode.
I hope it was helpful :)

Comment: I think you need to do String.fromCharCode here

Comment: *"You shouldn't take as true the supposition about Javascript uses ASCII character table (doesn't it use UTF8?)"* It uses UTF-16, actually. But it doesn't matter in this case. ASCII and Unicode share the same first 127 values, by design. The bigger issue is that this is a very naïve definition of "upper case" and "lower case" that fails easily. For instance, looking at that last sentence, is the "ï" in "naïve" lower case? I think it is, I'm pretty sure the French think it is, but this code does not. (And "naïve" is an English word, we just copied it from the French a while back.)

Comment: @TjCrowder: And the non-borrowed "encyclopædia" vs "ENCYCLOPÆDIA".

Comment: how does one type Æ on a keyboard?(I cut and paste it)

Answer (score 0):

don't use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) here - it is not correct syntax and charCode is an int so no need to parseInt it

```
    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <=90) //UPPERCASE
        alert("UP");
    else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <=122) //LOWERCASE
        alert("LO");
    else if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <=57) // NUMBERS
        alert("NUM");
```

UPDATE: How about
[fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```
var char = String.fromCharCode(charCode)

if (/[a-z]/.test(char)) alert("Lower");
else if (/[A-Z]/.test(char)) alert("Upper");
else if (/[0-9]/.test(char)) alert("Numbers");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v65Xc/

I am sure someone can put this in an object or use prototype :)

Comment: Hi, charCode is an int, and Swicth is the exact syntax to use rather than an ugly string of if else's.

Comment: @thebounder: If `charCode` is an int, why are you calling `parseInt` on it?

Comment: There are only three in the example I gave.

Comment: Help! `if (/[a-z]/.test(char) alert("Lower");
else if (/[A-Z]/.test(char) alert("Upper");
else if (/[0-9]/.test(char) alert("Numbers");` doesn't pass http://JsHint.com

Comment: missing end brackets. Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this website for functions and explanation related to your problem. Sorry but none of them takes in consideration  the problem related to non-ascii chars like 'ï' or 'ö'
http://javascript.about.com/library/blvalid02.htm