# Javascript inoperant Switch Case with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, case, switch-statement

It looks like the javascript *switch case* doesn't like the regex as a case as it works with static values but I can't get the expected answers using regex in the *case* statement.

Would you pls confirm that limitation of the js interpretor and propose a work around (I mean not a if-then blocks suite) ?

Thx

**example** (not giving the expected answer ,eg 'case3') :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var testme = "pwd_foo";
var response = false;
var reg = /^pwd.+/;

switch (testme) {
case 'pwd':
    response = 'case1';
    break;
case reg.test:
    response = 'case2';
    break;
case /^pwd.+/:
   response = 'case3';
   break;
default:
    response = 'do sthg else';
}

alert('reg test: ' + reg.test(testme)+'\nresponse:' + response);
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your tests do not really lend themselves to a switch. If you must, you can do this which is NOT RECOMMENDED:

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rVmXN/)

```
var testme = "pwd_foo", response;
var reg = /^pwd.+/;

switch (true) {
case testme=='pwd':
    response = 'case1';
    break;
case reg.test(testme):
    response = 'case2';
    break;
default:
    response = 'do sthg else';
}

alert('reg test: ' + reg.test(testme)+'\nresponse:' + response);
```

Comment: Mmmm, I remember a certain comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395171/switch-statement-in-javascript/6395203#6395203

Comment: Haha - my past comes back to haunt me ;) Please note the "If you must"

Comment: especially for you, I added a nice ternary solution >-D

Comment: Non-commenting down voters should be banned ! - this has been specifically noted as a workaround, not a best practise!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a ternary for this (but *do* see the [disclaimer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395171/switch-statement-in-javascript/6395203#6395203)):

```
var testme = "pwd_foo", 
    response = 
       testme === 'pwd' 
         ? 'case1' 
         : /^pwd.+/.test(testme) 
           ? 'case2' 
           : 'do something else';
```

Comment: thx but that's not what I was looking for, as my question is trying to simplify the real case I need. No doubt, I need a switch case for my particular purpose. I used the switch(true) which works like a charm.

Comment: That's ok. It's just a demonstration of an alternative and a little teaser for @mplungjan who in a previous life demonstrated an aversion for ternaries (and the `switch(true)` construction for that matter)