# Javascript String Character Checking

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to check that a javascript string is at least four characters long, contains at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter and a digit?

Comment: Sharing some code would be the best way, I guess...

Comment: Regular expressions, I guess..

Comment: What methods have you tried already? What problems did you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing for lowercase letters [has already been covered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830826/javascript-checking-for-any-lowercase-letters-in-a-string):

```
function hasLowerCase(str) {
    return (/[a-z]/.test(str));
}
```

It's trivial to modify that to implement `hasUpperCase` and `hasDigits`.

Once you have written these functions, you can just check that:

```
if( hasLowerCase(passwd) && hasUpperCase(passwd) && hasDigits(passwd) ) {
    // Its a valid password!
}
```

If you use it in many places, consider making a new function:

```
function isPasswordValid(str) {
    return hasLowerCase(passwd) && hasUpperCase(passwd) && hasDigits(passwd);
}
```

Which you can further use like:

```
if( isPasswordValid("passwd") ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already looked at regular expressions and that example but am not too familiar with regex. Would it possible to have one regex statement  or would I need three statements - one for the lower, upper and digit cases, then check that all three are true?

Comment: Yes you can do exactly that!

Comment: OK so I'll need a check for all three.

Comment: Testing for all three in one regex is not a good idea because you don't know what order they're in.

Comment: Wow stop! I definitely meant using THREE regexes just for this exactly same reason! Sorry for ambiguity!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick validation function:

```
function validate(str) {
    return str.length > 3 && /[a-z]/.test(str) && /[A-Z]/.test(str) && /[0-9]/.test(str) ;
}
```

It checks the length and then runs regular expressions looking for lowercase, uppercase and numbers (in that order). If all are true (length > 3 `and` has lowercase `and` has uppercase `and` has a number) it returns `true`. Otherwise, it returns `false`.

use it like this:

```
validate("aaaa")  // returns false
validate("aA1")   // returns false
validate("aA12")  // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function, same like `ColBeseder` .added a type checking `string`

```
function check( str ){

    return ( typeof str == 'string') &&
           ( str.length >= 4 ) &&
           /[a-z]/.test( str ) &&
           /[A-Z]/.test( str ) && 
           /[0-9]/.test( str )

}
```

and call its as `check('AAA1a')` , which returns a boolean